# How to count distinct elements in a sorted sequence without using an array?

Tags: c, sequence

I want to count distinct elements in the sequence before -1 is encountered without using array.

I have tried an attempt to do it but, it is counting all the elements. I am unable to put the checking condition for the same elements (because I am not using array).

```
for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&a);

  if (a==-1)
  {
    printf("%d",count);
  }
  else
  {
    count=count+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is this a homework question?  2. please format your code

Comment: Perhaps you could use a linked list instead of an array?

Comment: just keep track of the last element you saw.  If the current one is different then increment your count

Comment: @jenesaisquoi what if numbers not sorted, this will fail

Comment: @LalitVerma read the title.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing about sorted lists/arrays. You know you will never another copy of an old number that you processed ages ago, since your numbers will only go up. That means, as pointed out in the comments, that you can simply compare with the previous value: if the current value is different, count up and update the previous value, otherwise do nothing. For example, if you have a predefined list:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    size_t n = 8;
    int list[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8};

    int prev = list[0];
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (list[i] != prev) {
            count++;
        }
        prev = list[i];
    }
    printf("final count: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are continuously reading with `scanf` you can switch to a loop that ends when it encounters EOF or a format error and get your current number that way instead of from `list[i]`.

In the list case you also know the starting condition, so you can skip the first step and initialize your `prev` and `count` like I did here. If you don't know the first element because you haven't read anything yet, you will also have to keep track of a first_element toggle, so your code should not compare when the first iteration of loop occurs.